# Feature selection with GridsearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am trying to use GridSearchCV to optimize a pipeline that does feature selection in the beginning and classification using KNN at the end. I have fitted the model using my data set but when I see the best parameters found by GridSearchCV, it only gives the best parameters for SelectKBest. I have no idea why it doesn't show the best parameters for KNN.

Here is my code.

**Addition of KNN and SelectKbest**

```
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()
parameters = {"classify__n_neighbors": list(range(5,15)),
                           "classify__p":[1,2]}
sel = SelectKBest(f_classif)
param={'kbest__k': [10, 20 ,30 ,40 ,50]}
```

**GridsearchCV with pipeline and parameter grid**

```
model = GridSearchCV(Pipeline([('kbest',sel),('classify', classifier)]),
                     param_grid=[param,parameters], cv=10)
```

**fitting the model**

```
model.fit(X_new, y)
```

**the result**

```
print(model.best_params_)
{'kbest__k': 40}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an incorrect way of merging dicts I believe. Try

```
param_grid={**param,**parameters}
```

or (Python 3.9+)

```
param_grid=param|parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

When `param_grid` is a list, the disjoint union of the grids generated by each dictionary in the list is explored.  So your search is over (1) the default `k=10` selected features and every combination of classifier parameters, and separately (2) the default classifier parameters and each value of `k`.  That the best parameters just show `k=40` means that having more features, even with default classifier, performed best.  You can check your `cv_results_` to verify.

As [dx2-66 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138823/10495893), merging the dictionaries will generate the full grid you probably are after.  You could also just define a single dictionary from the start.